# How to set content length for file downloaded using URL class, using Java/Spring MVC?

Tags: java, ajax, file, spring-mvc, download

Following is Java code used to download file in Spring MVC Ajax call. 
I need to set Content Length which I am unable to find using URL.openStream().

```
URL fileToDownload = new URL(form.getDownloadLink());

InputStream fileContents = fileToDownload.openStream();
response.setContentType("application/docx");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+fileName+"");
response.setContentLength(<Length>);

ServletOutputStream outputFile = response.getOutputStream(); 
IOUtils.copy(fileContents, outputFile);
response.flushBuffer();
fileContents.close();
outputFile.close();
```

Could anyone guide how to get length of Stream?

We download PDF and DOCX files of different sizes using above